# Downloading file from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, c++17, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file via my AWS S3 bucket by using this code I found on github: [curl_bazek](https://github.com/vnvo2409/curl_bazel/blob/a826912a8fb2844ea4dabf818185af206a2fd06c/main/main.cc)

I was able to get it working by fixing some issues with the code. Hardcoding the Access and Secret key and adjusting the time to GMT. But I'm lost in how to download the file.

Here's my output and you can see the test.dll is located in this bucket:

```
AWSSecretKey=XXXXXXX
https://XXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>atmaple</Name><Prefix>

</Prefix><Marker></Marker><MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated><Contents><Key>test.dll</Key>
<LastModified>2021-06-29T16:18:40.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>&quot;XXXXXXXXXXXXX&quot;</ETag>
<Size>45634048</Size><Owner><ID>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</ID></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents></ListBucketResult>
```

Changing the url leads me to an error.

```
std::string hostS3Bucket = bucketName + ".s3.amazonaws.com/test.dll";
```

Changing the curl url also leads to the same effect.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ("https://" + hostS3Bucket + "/test.dll").c_str());
```

The error:

```
The specified bucket is not valid.
```

Comment: You might want to use: [AWS SDK for C++](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the method is so much cleaner in SDK for C++, thank you for the suggestion. I was able to solve my issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Aws::SDKOptions options;
            Aws::InitAPI(options);
            {
                const Aws::String bucket_name = "bucket";
                const Aws::String object_name = "test.dll";
                const Aws::String region = "us-east-1";

                Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;

                if (!region.empty())
                {
                    config.region = region;
                }

                Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
                credentials.SetAWSAccessKeyId("accesskey");
                credentials.SetAWSSecretKey("secretkey");

                Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(credentials, config);

                Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
                object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name);
                object_request.SetKey(object_name);

                Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome get_object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(object_request);

                if (get_object_outcome.IsSuccess())
                {
                    auto& retrieved_file = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();
                    int size = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetContentLength() + 1;
                }
            }
            Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```

This worked for me. I load the .dll via memory, so I don't need to handle actually writing to disk, but seems the SDK also handles this if needed.

Regards